# Jquery not working for the content inside the ng-view element

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am using AngularJS to build SPA(single page app).i have multiple pages which has linked to jquery.js. when i run the pages separately all the jquery functions successfully executing, but when i access those files from the ng-view element. the jquery from other pages is not at all executing. 
What may be the problem?

Comment: You should go through [“Thinking in AngularJS” if I have a jQuery background?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

Comment: Do you have a code example?

Comment: downvote???? what's happening here? I just give author an upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by just removing

```
$(document).ready(function(){    });
```

which is inside the embedded pages.
Now jquery in all other pages is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `angular.element('#element')` instead of `jQuery(#element)` or `$(#element)`. Any manipulation done with `jQuery` might not be reflected in your angular state.